# Asp.net Html.Action perfomance

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

i'm developing an asp.net mvc 5 web application using a page that is compose by around 10 module.
I'm implementing each module using a partialview with Html.action, that calling an action that get data from a web api
My doubt is about performance. Can Html.action destroy performance ?

Thank you

Comment: (Mis)use of anything can destroy performance. You should profile your code and see how it performs, and then you can make a judgement on whether it's good enough or if you need to rethink your approach. :)

Comment: `@Html.Action` is performed on the server before being passed to the browser. If each method is not duplicating a call to a service or repeating code there should not be any significant performance difference. Note also that `Html.RenderAction()` has better performance that `Html.Action()` if your rendering a large amount of html.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends upon the data and its dependency over the populated view

***Html.Action***

> Action method is useful when the displaying data in the partial view
>   is independent from corresponding view model.For example : In a blog
>   to show category list on each and every page, we would like to use
>   Action method since the list of category is populated by the different
>   model.

```
@{Html.Action("Category","Home");}
```

***Html.Partial***

> Partial method is useful used when the displaying data in the partial
>   view is already in the corresponding view model.For example : In a
>   blog to show comments of an article, we would like to use
>   RenderPartial method since an article information with comments are
>   already populated in the view model.

```
@Html.Partial("_Comments")
```